# Bootstrap Overlay Clickable With Link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hopefully I'm able to provide enough code here, but I'm hoping for some assistance with a Bootstrap image gallery I am building.  Currently, I have a variety of images that appear in a portfolio, and upon rollover, an "overlay" appears, along with an icon that a user can click on to open a Lightbox;

```
<div class="container-fluid full-width">
  <div class="row row-no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-push-0 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-push-0 content">
      <div class="isotope_items">
        <div class="single_item link web-design col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="work-inner">
            <div class="work-overlay">  
              <div class="overlay-in">
                <div class="work-info">   
                  <div class="work-links">                                             
                    <a href="images/work-1.jpg" class="image-link lightbox"><i data-icon="W" class="icon" style="color:white"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <a href="images/work-1.jpg" class="image-link lightbox"><img src="images/work-1.jpg" class="img-full-width" alt="" ></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Relevant CSS;

```
.work-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.work-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.overlay-in {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.work-info {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.overlay-in p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.overlay-in .work-links {
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}


.overlay-in .work-links a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay-in .work-links a:hover{ 
  opacity:0.5;
}

.work-inner:hover > .work-overlay{ 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.work-inner:hover .overlay-in p{
  opacity:1;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 24px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s; 
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.work-inner:hover .overlay-in .work-links{
  opacity:1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
```

What I'm after doing, however, is making it so the entire image can be clicked, rather than just the *data icon*.  As you can imagine, only having the icon be clickable is creating an issue for mobile devices that cannot accurately click the icon.

*Updated code - Sorry for length!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit with solution:**

After our discussion and viewing the sample code you posted at [35.153.183.88/portfolio](http://35.153.183.88/portfolio), we determined that the solution to this issue was simply to move the anchor tag from your icon to encompass the div that triggers your overlay.

So, having your anchor tag like so:

```
// Other Divs
<div class="work-inner">
    <a href="images/work-1.jpg" class="image-link lightbox">
        <div class="work-overlay"> 
             // Other divs/image/icon.
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I've left my original suggestion below for historical context.

**/*======== Deprecated answer below. ========*/**

Whatever is inside the anchor tag will be the link. If the structure of the template doesn't allow for you to move the the image inside the anchor tag, then you could either try duplicating the anchor tag around the image as well, or perhaps just moving to the image and removing it from the icon.

I didn't include all your divs below because formatting that here is a nightmare.

**Duplicated:**

`<a href="images/work-1.jpg" class="image-link lightbox"><i data-icon="W" class="icon" style="color:white"></i></a>`

Then...

`<a href="images/work-1.jpg" class="image-link lightbox"><img src="images/work-1.jpg" class="img-full-width" alt="" ></a>`

**Moved to Image Only**

`<i data-icon="W" class="icon" style="color:white"></i>`

Then...

`<a href="images/work-1.jpg" class="image-link lightbox"><img src="images/work-1.jpg" class="img-full-width" alt="" ></a>`

The the second one, if you need to retain the link styling for the icon, you would add the "image-link lightbox" css classes into the icon's classes:

`<i data-icon="W" class="icon image-link lightbox" style="color:white"></i>`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  I did indeed try moving the anchor to surround the img tag, and not the data-icon, but despite this providing me the proper cursor, clicking on the image doesn't do anything (it almost seems like the overlay is preventing the anchor from being effective)

Comment: @ZbadhabitZ If possible, can you provide a more complete snippet of your code so that we can better understand the issue?

Comment: @ZbadhabitZ I grabbed your updated code and threw it into a JSFiddle with a placeholder image. Is this accurate to what you've currently got?
https://jsfiddle.net/persononfire/yysuqsjq/5/

Comment: The JSFiddle is similar.  I've uploaded a sample of the work here:  http://35.153.183.88/portfolio/.  As you'll see from that, I do succeed in getting the dark gray overlay to appear over the image on rollover, but if tested on a mobile device, such as iPhone or iPad, the user experience has an issue with getting to the link.

Comment: @ZbadhabitZ Thank you, that's a lot easier to see what's going on. So from looking at that I believe it's just as simple as moving your anchor tag to encompass your <div class="work-inner">. So the </a> for the anchor should be after the closing tag for the div.

Comment: Yes, that worked!  Thank you, Ryan!  I've updated the link to demonstrate.  I can happily mark answer as correct as needed.

Comment: @ZbadhabitZ Excellent. I'll update the answer to reflect the solution and you can mark it. Having a working demo of the code always makes it easier to understand/troubleshoot. :)